# Why was this question rejected?

Tags: discussion

This [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/27825/can-a-single-sentence-be-made-using-words-to-too-and-two-consecutively-one-af) by @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish was rejected as off-topic, but it seems to me to be puzzling and pleasantly challenging, thus within "creation and solving of puzzles".

It was proposed for migration from [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/306268/can-a-single-sentence-be-made-using-words-to-too-and-two-consecutively-one-af) and they put it on hold when migration was rejected (I plan to query there as well).

Edit: ELU have explained their decision [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7729/why-was-this-question-put-on-hold) and I can accept their explanation.

Please explain to me why it was rejected on p.s.e.

Edit: by "why it was rejected" I mean "why is it considered unsuitable for Puzzling.SE"?

Comment: This question has lots of possible answers, so I might have VTC'd as too broad for puzzling.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Without any restriction, can a **single sentence** be written or spoken using the words "to", "too", and "two" in the same sentence consecutively used (one after the other) and be proper?

That is the main question seen the post you linked. This is basically a yes/no question, not a question with lots of possible answers and interpretations of the question in which only one is correct. The question can be answered correctly by choosing the correct answer (yes or no) followed by a reasonable explanation on why you chose one of those two options.

Now this question is way too broad: all you need is a sentence with "to two too" at the end. With all the *possible answers* with such a *narrow question* requesting either yes or no with an explanation makes no sense and is off-topic here.

> but it seems to me to be puzzling and pleasantly challenging, thus within "creation and solving of puzzles"

I can understand your view on the question but as I said above, the question basically only has one answer: "yes" plus a sentence to explain why it is possible. It is not challenging like other puzzles, where users might see other ways other from the actual answer and is though-provoking.

Comment: Thanks @PythonMaster for taking the time to explain.